# How Can I save my output to files with using cmd.exe in command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run `cmd.exe "D:a.bat"` but am not getting anything. 
It works when I run the batch file by double clicking it.

The code in the batch file is:

```
echo teztttttt >> a.txt
```

Can someone help me understand why is running the command using cmd.exe is not producing the expected result.

Comment: what error do you get? And also what is `D:a.bat`?? Don't you mean `D:\a.bat`??

Comment: There really shouldn't be any need to run the .bat file as a parameter to cmd.exe.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you don't need to invoke cmd.exe to execute a batch script. The typical way for one batch script to call another is to use `call "D:a.bat" >> a.txt`.

But I will assume you have a good reason to run your script via cmd.exe.

Read the documentation (`cmd /?` from a command prompt) and you will see that you must prefix your command with `/C`.

```
cmd.exe /c "D:a.bat"
```

Not an issue with the code you have shown, but if you read the help carefully, you will see there is some funny business with how cmd.exe handles quotes.

If you must quote the script due to spaces and/or poison characters, and you also have subsequent arguments with quotes, then you may not get what you desire, because cmd.exe will remove the first and last quote.

For example:

```
cmd.exe /c "my script.bat" "this&that"
```

will attempt (and most likely fail) to execute

```
my script.bat" "this&that
```

where

- `my` is the first program name, and `script.bat" "this` is the 1st argument
- `&` is the command concatenation operator (it is not quoted or escaped)
- `that` is a second command

The problem is fixed by enclosing the entire command line in an extra set of escaped quotes:

```
cmd.exe /c ^""my script.bat" "this&that"^"
```

The outer quotes are initially escaped, so the `&` is properly quoted. Then when cmd.exe strips off the outer quotes, you are left with the correct command string.